# Database problem after moving the site: unknown server error

Tags: database, configuration

I just moved my site onto the server and put it under /drupal_test directory. I now have got an error in the browser, but there is no errors in the apache error log:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'http://www.mydomain.com' (1)
in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /var/www/drupal_test/includes/lock.inc).
```

I have searched around online, many suggests that this is a problem with settings.php, but I can't see any problem with my settings:

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'websitedb',
      'username' => 'websitedbusername',
      'password' => 'thepassword',
      'host' => 'http://www.mydomain.com',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

I tried to use the ip address as the host, I got an error like this:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2013] Lost connection to MySQL server at
'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111 in lock_may_be_available()
(line 167 of /var/www/drupal_test/includes/lock.inc).
```

Also, my current site www.mydomain.com works fine.

Any help will be very much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Database host should be `mydomain.com` not `http://www.mydomain.com`

Comment: What @user11153 says - MySQL does **not use http** protocol, it uses mysql protocol. And you don't need to tell that when system knows you are configuring mysql ant=yway ;)

Comment: Hello again. Your last edit changed the meaning of your question, making it a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). Please consider a rollback and asking new question.

Comment: If it's running on the same system then use localhost/127.0.0.1 as database host for efficiency & portability.

Comment: localhost?? I didn't know you can use localhost on a real host server, isn't localhost only for LOCAL HOST? Thanks

Comment: @the_summer_bee from the point of view of the real host server, he is local and you are remote ;)

Comment: Thank you so much @Mołot, I had no idea that it should be localhost! That was it, it just worked! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the above database configuration the problem seems to be with the `host`, you need to enter the "database hostname", or try entering the static ip "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" of the database host.

Aslo check the credentials of your database if they are correct or not. Discussion about the same issue faced be other people is available at: https://drupal.org/node/1315592 .

Comment: Hi, thanks, but as I edited, then I got a new error regarding lost connection to MySQL...

Comment: Are the database credentials correct, this error seems to be because of database connection not getting established.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are right, I checked this in the server as well. I used the accounts access the database through putty the command lines, all works fine..

Comment: I also tried to set root as database user, still doesn't work

Comment: It means the problem is with the host name only, so please once confirm the "database hostname"

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot.  I added the ip for 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost on mac OS X 10.10.3 and everything worked.

Comment: @AgnosticDev I m Glad it helped you!